# Squish H5 files

Tags: python, hdf, squish

I am trying to extract data from HDF files and compare the data. Is it possible to automate the process using Squish? Also how to compare data of 2 HDf files of different versions? I am very new to this and have no clue how to start. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you do some research before asking?

Answer (score 0):

If the HDF files are basically plain text, it may be possible to use [test.compareTextFiles()](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#test.compareTextFiles-function).

If you can convert the HDF files to XML and you can use [test.compareXMLFiles()](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#test.compareXMLFiles-function), which gains you the ability to ignore dynamic portions more easily.

And in general, if you can find any tools that do what you need (extraction, comparison/diff) then you can use them in Squish test scripts (see [Article - Executing external applications](https://kb.froglogic.com/display/KB/Article+-+Executing+external+applications)).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried test.compareXMLFiles() as suggested , but the problem  is  it will stop the comparison at the first encountered difference.

Comment: Isn't it so that any difference results in the comparison to fail anyway? Why do you want to proceed looking for more differences? I recommend to contact the vendor to have your requirements heard.